# resizing TableView to fit ScrollPane

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, javafx

i have a little problem to layout a `TableView` inside a `ScrollPane` :

i want to know how to make the `TableView` always fit inside the `ScrollPane`, What happen is :

- when i make the windows small everything work good there is a scroll bar and that work
- but when i make the windows larger the `TableView` don't grow with the `ScrollPane`, so how to make it work, i have tried to set `fitWidth` of ScrollPane to true, but if i do the TableView Column are just resized with the size of the window there is no scrollbar

[image]

Comment: Unlike Swing, a JavaFX TableView should not be placed in a ScrollPane.  It already handles scrolling on its own.

Comment: but when i add a lot of table column they  just get add with the half of their name remplaced by **...** and no ScrollBar is added

Comment: Call `setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY)` on the `TableView`.

Comment: Already set but not working.

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE] ?

Comment: Sorry: that should have been `UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY`. Note that the resizing doesn't seem to work unless there is some content in the table.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using scene builder to construct your fxml, it's very easy to do this. Just select the scrollPane which wrap your tableview and check option "Fit to Width" in Layout. However, you can also do the same work in code by checking your scrollpane object but not tableview object.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put `TableView` in `UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY` mode